# Integrating a differential form

Tags: integration, differential-forms

I am currently going through Introduction to Smooth manifolds by John Lee and am a bit confused with the integration of differential forms.

So given a smooth k-form $\omega = f dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k $ on some integral domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ we can integrate $\omega$ over $D$, which is given in the book by
$$\int_D f dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k = \int_D f dx^1 ... dx^k \, \, \, \,  \, \, (\star)$$

What I am confused about is that if we interchange say the $dx^1$ and the $dx^2$ in both sides of the equation we get a negative side arising on the left as $dx^1 \wedge dx^2 = - dx^2 \wedge dx^1$, whilst on the right hand side there will be no sign factor as $dx^1 dx^2 =dx^2 dx^1$.

Is the reason that the above is not a contradiction a result of the fact we have fixed an orientation $(x^1, ..., x^k)$, and so with this orientation  we get that $(\star)$ holds but 
$$\int_D f dx^2 \wedge dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k \neq \int_D f dx^2 dx^1 dx^3 ... dx^k?$$

That is, we can only integrate once we have ordered the differential form into its chosen orientation?

Comment: You have deviously :) omitted the previous sentence: "*This can be written more suggestively as...*" but the strict definition is $\int_D w=\int_D f dV$, which in turn requires reading the previous 10 pages about the definition of orientation. But even that is not completely strict until the definition of **volume form** in the next Section.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula  should be written
$$\int_D f(x)\> dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k = \int_D f(x)\>{\rm d}(x)\ , \tag{$\star$}$$
insofar as on the right hand side there is not meant a product of first order differentials of any sort, but integration with respect to standard, and in particular:  orientation independent, Lebesgue measure in ${\mathbb R}^k$. The formula $(\star)$ on the other hand involves a choice of orientation: It says that the products differring by an even permutation from $dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k$ are considered positive, i.e., in line with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Okay so if we had instead chosen the orientation $(x^2,x^1,x^3,...,x^k)$ as the positively oriented coordinates, would it be correct that $\int_D f(x) dx^2 \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^3 \wedge ... \wedge dx^k = \int_D f(x) d(x)$?

Comment: I think I'm getting confused because I feel the right hand side is orientation independent but the left is orientation dependent

Comment: @Arrow The right-hand side *is* orientation-dependent, just that the orientation is hidden inside the volume form.